# removeFrom(map) doesn't work

Tags: javascript, leaflet

```
 omnivore.wkt.parse("${feature}").removeFrom(map);
```

I select features by this line 
 omnivore.wkt.parse("${feature}").addTo(map);
but when I remove from map doesn't work

this code works but if I don't know delete feature

```
<c:if test="${not empty mapBean.layers}"> console.log('Kaydedilen featurelar:');
<c:forEach var="layer" items="${mapBean.layers}"> <c:if test="${layer.id==1}"> <c:if test="${not empty layer.features}"> <c:forEach var="feature" items="${layer.features}"> console.log("${feature}"); 
omnivore.wkt.parse("${feature}").addTo(map); </c:forEach> </c:if> </c:if> </c:forEach> </c:if>
```

Comment: You need to remove the layer from the map (map.removeLayer(your_layer), not from a wkt.parse object.

Comment: but I added feature not layer

Comment: I tried map.removeLayer also doesn't work

Comment: <c:if test="${not empty mapBean.layers}">
  console.log('Kaydedilen featurelar:');
  <c:forEach var="layer" items="${mapBean.layers}">
  <c:if  test="${layer.id==1}">
  <c:if  test="${not empty layer.features}">
  <c:forEach var="feature" items="${layer.features}">
   console.log("${feature}");
    omnivore.wkt.parse("${feature}").addTo(map);
  </c:forEach>
   </c:if>
   </c:if>
  </c:forEach>
 </c:if>
this code works 
but if I don't know delete feature

Comment: There is an **edit** button beneath your question that you should use to improve it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: I didn't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`omnivore.wkt.parse` [returns a layer](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore)

```
// adding
var feature = omnivore.wkt.parse("${feature}");
feature.addTo(map);

// removing: feature.removeFrom() is not a function, use map.removeLayer()
map.removeLayer(feature);
```